# Finding max frequency of character used in a given string

Tags: python, lambda, iterable-unpacking

In the following piece of code I'm trying to find the most used character in a given sentence. I've used list unpacking, and I've seen different ways of solving this. My question is, is this a good way to do it? or it's too complicated and not clean?

***Input***

```
sentence = "This is a common interview question"
characters = list(
    {
        (char, sentence.count(char))
        for char in sentence if char != ' '
    }
)

characters.sort(
    key=lambda char: char[1],
    reverse=True
)

print(f"'{characters[0][0]}' is repeated {characters[0][1]} times")
```

***Output***

```
'i' is repeated 5 times
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is for answering specific, objective programming questions. Requests for general review and critique are consider to be off-topic, and should be directed to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As a side note, your approach runs in `O(n^2)` time when `O(n)` is possible, constructs an unnecessary intermediate `set`, and neglects to use common standard library functionality such as `collections.Counter` or `operator.itemgetter`. You also take a performance hit by using the `list` builtin over an iterable rather the a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections` package:

```
import collections
s = "This is a common interview question"
print(collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```